# django template show content only in a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a Django HTML template as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Cloud | Review {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog">
        <p>Testing a simple Dialog box.</p>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        function EditDialog() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            return false;
        }
    </script>

     <div class="function-page">
         <div class="table-form">
                <div class="function-container">
                    {% render_table reviews %}
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The jquery dialog box is launched when the user clicks a link. The issue is when the page is loaded, the `div` contents are shown at the top of the page

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">
    <p>Testing a simple Dialog box.</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to show this content only in the jquery dialog and not in the usual page content.

Also, once I show the dialog box by called `EditDialog()` the div disappears from the main underlying page.

Comment: You want to hide this dialogue when this page load?

Comment: The dialog is hidden. It does not show. It is the `<div id="dialog" title="Dialog">` that should be hidden or rather only viewed in the jquery dialog.

Comment: Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simply:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog" style="display: none;">
    <p>Testing a simple Dialog box.</p>
</div>
```

did the trick